# How to plot communities with node IDs?

Tags: python, plot, graph, nodes

I am being asked to plot the communities with node ids (labels):

- when community has more than 15 nodes, plot it in red color
- when community has less than 10 nodes, plot it in green color
- when community has 10<=size<=15 nodes, plot it in orange color

I was trying:

```
if community < 10:
  nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, node_color='green')
```

but am getting a syntax error. Could someone help me with this?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :^D We'll need more code to troubleshoot this.  More of the error message would also be helpful.  For a helpful guide on how to write a good question that includes code for troubleshooting, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the error I am getting:   
File "<ipython-input-26-327a6d4ab6c2>", line 8
    if community 10<=size<=15:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It's hard to tell without a *longer block of code* and the definition of `community`, but it looks like you're using the `community` variable to hold the size of the community.  Comparing to your other small snippet, it looks like line 8 should be `if 10 <= community <= 15:`.